# twitter API trend by place

Tags: laravel, twitter, twitter-oauth, hashtag, trend

I am using Twitter Api with laravel App, I am trying to get top trends hashtag to my country, my control code :

```
$trends=Twitter::get(‘https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1’);
```

on my view:

```
@foreach($trends as $trend)
    {{$trend->text}}
@endforeach
```

I know `id=1` is not my country id, but there is no result and the error:

> [34] Sorry, that page does not exist.

I am using laravel framework. Can any one help me?

Comment: `get(‘...’)` - is that literally what you have in your code?  Those quotes are not single quotes, they are curly or 'smart' quotes which won't work in PHP.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No its a single quotes ' '